# De-normalization alternative to specific MYSQL problem?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, caching, denormalization

I am facing quite a specific optimization problem.

I currently have 4 normalized tables of data.

Every second, possibly thousands of users will pull down up-to-date info from these tables using AJAX.

The thing is that I can predict relatively easily which subset of data they need... The most recent 100 or so entries in those 4 normalized tables.

I have been researching de-normalization... but feel that perhaps there is an easier solution.

I was thinking that I could somehow every second run one sql query to condense the needed info, store it in a temp cached table and then have all of the user queries just draw from this. This will allow the complex join of 4 tables to only be run once, and then from there the users just need to do a simple lookup from the cached table.

I really don't know if this is feasible. Comments on this or any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Are you able to employ [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)?

It helps to lessen db load.

Comment: +1 This is the simplest and best answer. Avoiding the database is your best bet.

Comment: Yes, perhaps. I am not too familiar with it but will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're running MySQL version 5.1.6 or later you can take advantage of [Events](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/event-feature.html):

```
CREATE EVENT e                 
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MINUTE                 
DO
INSERT INTO tempTable (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) 
    SELECT `col1`,`col2`,`col3`
    FROM table1
    WHERE col1 = "value"
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with query caching?

```
Select SQL_CACHE * from myTable  inner join etc..... ;
```

if the data changes often then this may not be of much/any help. (The cache will automatically invalidate every time the data changes.)

Note: always gaurd your database so, if you can try cache outside of the db.
also you may need to check the variables `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE %query_cache%` to ensure query caching is on.

Answer (score 1):

Denormalization shouldn't be a result of `thinking`. But of testing. 
**What are problem queries?** Do you have any?

Does your other equipment - hardware, web-server, business logic layer ready to such a traffic? Or your question is just imagination?